# Dash core component for basic Button with click event?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm trying to create an app with multiple tabs for different sets of information. My first thought was to use html Buttons but there's not dash_core_component for this, and I can't find documentation on anything I can use in it's place. Basically, when I click a button (or link), I'd like to get a "clicked" event with the id of the button so I can redraw the layout for the selected page.

Is there a way to do this with existing components? Is there documentation on how to create new components that can be wired into the callback system? I feel like I must be missing something obvious, but I've failed to find anything after a lot of searching.

Comment: Note that the [html.Button](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-html-components/button) component is now fully documented.

Answer (score 11):

In fact, they do have a click event available for a button in the latest `dash_html_components`, but it doesn't appear to be fully documented yet. The creator, chriddyp, has [stated](https://community.plot.ly/t/is-there-a-way-to-only-update-on-a-button-press-for-apps-where-updates-are-slow/4679/7) that the `Event` object may not be future-proof, but that `State` should be.

Using `State` like:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('output', 'children'),
    [Input('button-2', 'n_clicks')],
    state=[State('input-1', 'value'),
     State('input-2', 'value'),
     State('slider-1', 'value')])
```

you can use values as inputs, without initiating the callback if they change -- instead waiting for the `Input('button', 'n_clicks')` to fire off the callback.

Copying full code example below from the link:

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Button('Click Me', id='button'),
    html.H3(id='button-clicks'),

    html.Hr(),

    html.Label('Input 1'),
    dcc.Input(id='input-1'),

    html.Label('Input 2'),
    dcc.Input(id='input-2'),

    html.Label('Slider 1'),
    dcc.Slider(id='slider-1'),

    html.Button(id='button-2'),

    html.Div(id='output')
])

@app.callback(
    Output('button-clicks', 'children'),
    [Input('button', 'n_clicks')])
def clicks(n_clicks):
    return 'Button has been clicked {} times'.format(n_clicks)

@app.callback(
    Output('output', 'children'),
    [Input('button-2', 'n_clicks')],
    state=[State('input-1', 'value'),
     State('input-2', 'value'),
     State('slider-1', 'value')])
def compute(n_clicks, input1, input2, slider1):
    return 'A computation based off of {}, {}, and {}'.format(
        input1, input2, slider1
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Aha! Finally found the answer, documented here: https://plot.ly/dash/urls

It would be nice to link this into the User Guide in a more obvious way (in the index?)

Comment: you are not answering the question. Links and buttons arent the same.