# How to use a button to trigger callback updates?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am just getting started with dash. Taking the example from [here](https://plot.ly/dash/getting-started-part-2#interactivity). I want to convert the dash app below

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Input(id='my-id', value='initial value', type="text"),
    html.Div(id='my-div')
])

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='my-div', component_property='children'),
    [Input(component_id='my-id', component_property='value')]
)
def update_output_div(input_value):
    return 'You\'ve entered "{}"'.format(input_value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

To update when the user presses a button not when the value of the input field changes. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: This turns out to be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45579844/dash-core-component-for-basic-button-with-click-event) question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a similar question to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45579844/dash-core-component-for-basic-button-with-click-event). There is a click event available for a button in the latest `dash_html_components`, but it doesn't appear to be fully documented yet. The creator, chriddyp, has [stated](https://community.plot.ly/t/is-there-a-way-to-only-update-on-a-button-press-for-apps-where-updates-are-slow/4679/7) that the `Event` object may not be future-proof, but that `State` should be.

Using `State` like:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('output', 'children'),
    [Input('button-2', 'n_clicks')],
    state=[State('input-1', 'value'),
     State('input-2', 'value'),
     State('slider-1', 'value')])
```

you can use values as inputs, without initiating the callback if they change. The callback only fires if the `Input('button', 'n_clicks')` updates.

So for your example, I've added a button and fed the State object your existing html.Input's value:

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Input(id='my-id', value='initial value', type="text"),
    html.Button('Click Me', id='button'),
    html.Div(id='my-div')
])

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='my-div', component_property='children'),
    [Input('button', 'n_clicks')],
    state=[State(component_id='my-id', component_property='value')]
)
def update_output_div(n_clicks, input_value):
    return 'You\'ve entered "{}" and clicked {} times'.format(input_value, n_clicks)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Answer (score -1):

For the first-time load, `n_clicks` might be `None`.

So, you can also have a check if you want nothing to show up when you load the app but only show up the result when the button is clicked.

```
if n_clicks is not None:
        if n_clicks>0:
            <your code>
```